# Retrieving values from nested JSON using GSON

Tags: java, json, api, gson, google-distancematrix-api

I'm working with JSON for the first time and my goal is to make an object with the properties Destination, Origin, and Duration from this JSON result (Google Distance Matrix API)

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "123 High St, Los Angeles, CA 90210, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "800 Lake Dr, Los Angeles, CA 90210, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "2.0 km",
                  "value" : 1969
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "6 mins",
                  "value" : 338
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

So far I have been able to correctly store destination and origin using this line
`Property data = new Gson().fromJson(json, Property.class);`
But I am having a very hard time figuring out how to get the values from inside the nests. Specifically, I'm trying to grab the "text" from duration.
Any help would be greatly apprciated!

Comment: Create an equivalent java class which can map to json object

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html

Answer (score 0):

First create a container for the surrounding data.

```
class MainContent
{
  public String destination_addresses;
  public String bar;
  public List<SubContent> subcontent;
}
```

Then you create a class for the nested data:

```
class SubContent
{
    public String text; 
}
```

The fields in either classes must have the same names as your json object does.

Then simply:

```
gson.fromJson(jsonData, MainContent.class);
```

GSON will attempt to reflect the values from the json string into the object.